# Add custom WordPress admin page with pretty url via code

Tags: plugins, customization, menus, wp-admin, rewrite-rules

WordPress `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` support adding custom page. The page created have url with a slug similar to `wp-admin/admin.php?page=our-custom-page`

How can create a admin page which will have a slug similar to `wp-admin/admin.php/our-custom-page`

I also want the pages to support inner routing similar to `wp-admin/admin.php/our-custom-page`

I know it can be done with server settings, I'm looking for way to created this from a theme/plugin.

The main goal is to create the custom admin page without any "?" of url params. The route is less important is long that it's inside `wp-admin/`

Answer (score 0):

> How can create a admin page which will have a slug similar to wp-admin/admin.php/our-custom-page

**You can't, this is not possible in WP Admin**

Unlike the frontend, WP Admin does not support pretty URLs, and has no rewrite rules system to plug into. What you're already using is the closest available solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be late for too long, but I just want to share my solution with future readers.

tldr;

```
# Inside your .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
...

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add This Line To your .htaccess file
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/our-custom-page/?$ wp-admin/admin.php?page=our-custom-page [L]
...
...
</IfModule>
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)